# Pseudo-class ::after doesn't work on img element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I tried to give my div and img element pseudo-class ::after when I hover them, but it's only work on the div element. It doesn't work with img element
Any solution?

```
.element {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 5.2rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: .75rem;
  margin-top: .75rem;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.element:hover::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  z-index: 7;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

```
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SAM-dev-pixel/fylo/main/img/illustration-intro.png" alt="" class="element">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SAM-dev-pixel/fylo/main/img/illustration-stay-productive.png" alt="" class="element">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SAM-dev-pixel/bookmark-landing-page/main/img/illustration-hero.svg" alt="" class="element">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images unfortunately don't support pseudo-elements like ::after or ::before. The easiest solution would be to wrap your images inside of a div and just give the class to the div. Like so

```
<div class="element">
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SAM-dev-pixel/fylo/main/img/illustration-intro.png" alt="" class="element">
</div>
```

This is also the case for e.g. `<input>` as these tags can't contain any content.

Comment: So img element can not be given ::after or ::before

Comment: That is correct